# Hot Module Replacement in angular 11

Tags: angular

I have an angular 10 project that I opened at work.
after a while, when I saw that HMR added to angular 11 I upgraded the project by trying to work with HMR.
Since it didn't, I opened a brand new angular project. checked that HMR working. I moved all components, services, modules, styles (without node folder of course) and launched it using `ng serve --hmr` and it failed to work again. the page is being refreshed.

I am on this 2 days. Any idea will be appreciated? thank you.
my package JSON is:

```
{
  "name": "date-manager-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

update: i opened a new brand angular 11 project, ran with --hmr.
i written alert() at AppComponent's ngOnInit.
i see that on each save,  ngOnInit is called ( alert pops up).
so, all code, ajax calls will be executed. isnt hmr suppose to bypass that?
if all code under ngOnInit executed, how hmr is helpful. what am i missing here?

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AppTest';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    alert();
  }
}
```

Comment: check this article hope it helps https://medium.com/echohub/implementation-of-hmr-hot-module-replacement-to-angular-project-f7bca523bd16

Comment: Try adding "ng serve --hmr" into the package.json and then npm start in cli

Comment: @Zam Abdul Vahid tried it now. added as you daid, and ran with npm start. it didnt work. maybe on of my dependencies failing it from working. thank you.


**
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --hmr",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
**

Comment: @A.T hi, this artical released at mat, angular 11 should support hmr out of the box,  they using angular 10 there. thanks man.

Comment: Note: If you're using Angular 12 on Windows HMR may not currently work properly due to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20891 - If your application is not loading try turning off hmr. This will require at least Angular 12.0.3 (which isn't yet out)

Answer (score 2):

Lets do it step by step.

1. Install the required hmr angular package.

   ```
   npm install @angularclass/hmr --save-dev
   ```
2. Add a new environment file called environment.hmr.ts inside your src/environments folder

   ```
   export const environment = {
     production: false,
     hmr: true
   }
   ```
3. Update 'build' & 'serve' properties in the angular.json

   ```
    "build": {
      "configurations": {
         //
        "hmr": {
           "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
            }
           ]
        }
        //
      }
    }

    "serve": {
        "configurations": {
            //
            "hmr": {
               "hmr": true,
               "browserTarget": "date-manager-ui:build:hmr"
            }
            //
        }
    }
   ```
4. Add 'node' into the types array in compilerOptions in src/tsconfig.app.json file.

   ```
   {
     //
     "compilerOptions": {
        //
        "types": ["node"]
     }
     //
   }
   ```
5. Now we need to add the hmr property with value 'false' in all other environment files except the newly added environment.hmr.ts file

   ```
   export const environment = {
     //
     hmr: false
   }
   ```
6. Lets configure our app to use hmr by creating a new file named hmr.ts inside src folder and finally by updating main.ts file as well.

   ```
   //hmr.ts
   import { NgModuleRef, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core'
   import { createNewHosts } from '@angularclass/hmr'

   export const hmrBootstrap = (
     module: any,
     bootstrap: () => Promise<NgModuleRef<any>>
   ) => {
   let ngModule: NgModuleRef<any>
   module.hot.accept()
   bootstrap().then(mod => (ngModule = mod))
   module.hot.dispose(() => {
   const appRef: ApplicationRef = ngModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef)
   const elements = appRef.components.map(c => c.location.nativeElement)
   const makeVisible = createNewHosts(elements)
   ngModule.destroy()
   makeVisible()
   })
   }

   //main.ts
   import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
   import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
   import { environment } from './environments/environment'
   import { hmrBootstrap } from './hmr'
   import { RootModule } from './app/root/root.module'

   if (environment.production) {
     enableProdMode()
   }

   const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(RootModule)

   if (environment.hmr) {
     if (module['hot']) {
        hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap)
     } else {
       console.error('HMR is not enabled for webpack-dev-server!')
       console.log('Are you using the --hmr flag for ng serve?')
     }
   } else {
     bootstrap().catch(err => console.log(err))
   }
   ```
7. Final step. Add hmr property in scripts object in the package.json file to make running app easier.

   ```
   "scripts": {
     //
     "hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr"
   }
   ```

Comment: This does not work for me on Angular 11, I have seen examples like this for older Angular versions. 
Compared to only using "ng serve --hmr"  it gets alot slower during compile/build

Angular CLI: 11.2.14
Node: 12.11.1
OS: win32 x64
typescript                      4.1.6
webpack                         4.46.0

Answer (score 1):

Updated to angular 12 today.
hmr started working.

Comment: Actually, Angular 12 has improved support for HMR and it almost work out of the box, this is the right answer.